# Finding possible determinant values of 3x3 matrix using an equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Given a 3 x 3 matrix $A$

$4A= A^{7}$ 
Find the possible values of det(A). I multiplied by $A^{-1}$ both sides and got
$4I= A^{6}$ (not helpful) ?? 
Can you show the right way to solve it ? and how does knowing that it's 3x3 help us ?

Comment: How can you be sure that $A$ is invertible (i.e. that $A^{-1}$ exists)?

Comment: For real matrices, you will end up with $3$ candidates. For completeness, one should show that there really are matrices that satisfy the equation and have the candidate as determinant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $4A=A^7$, then $\det(4A)=\det(A^7)=[\det(A)]^7=4^3\det(A)$

Since $\det(cA)=c^n\det(A)$

Let $\det(A)=x$, then we must solve $64x=x^7$

Answer (score 1):

you use  $\det(xA)=x^3 \det(A)$ and $\det(A^7)=(\det(A))^7$

Answer (score 1):

Taking determinants of both sides and using the multiplicativity of $\det()$, you get $64\det(A) = \det(A)^7$. So $\det(A) = 0$ or $\det(A)^6 = 64$. (Note that $\det(A)$ can be $0$, so you CAN'T multiply by $A^{-1}$; $A$ may not be invertible.)

Now simply solve $x^6 = 64$. You didn't say if $A$ has elements in $\mathbb C$ or $\mathbb R$. Solve in the proper domain.

Finally, for completeness, let $x = 0$ or $x^6 = 64$. You must show that there is at least a matrix $A$ such that $\det(A) = x$. This is easy; let $A$ be a diagonal matrix, with elements $\sqrt[3]{x}$, $\sqrt[3]{x}$, $\sqrt[3]{x}$ along the diagonal.

Comment: @MartinArgerami - No, why? In $\mathbb R$ there are two solutions ($2$ and $-2$) and in $\mathbb C$ there are six solutions, why just $2$?

Comment: Yes, you are right. My bad.